# Как получить объект из stdClass Object массива

Tags: массивы, json

Привет. Я только начинаю, не пинайте сильно.
Есть массив

```
Array ( [result] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 24 ) ) [total] => 1 )
```

Из него мне нужно получить ID,
total я получил так

```
$obj = json_decode($obj);
$obj = (array)$obj;
$obj = $obj['total'];
```

А вот ID мне никак не удается вывести, подскажите, пожалуйста, куда копать

Answer (score 0):

```
json_decode($obj, true);
```

Описание функции:

```
mixed json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = false [, int $depth = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]] )
```

Если TRUE, возвращаемые объекты будут преобразованы в ассоциативные массивы.

[Ссылка на документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php)

Соответственно, чтоб получить `ID` обращаемся как к элементу массива:

```
$arr['result'][0]['ID']
```

Comment: Array ( [result] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [ID] => 24 ) ) [total] => 1 ) выводит так когда поставил TRUE

Comment: @AndrewBlack даже не в резулт, а еще раньше.... то есть если у тебя написано так `$arr = Array ( [result] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [ID] => 24 ) ) [total] => 1 )`  значит надо брать результат так `$arr['total']`

Comment: да total то я вывел, вот на ID мозгов не хватает, подозреваю что просто, но не получается

Comment: @AndrewBlack так это получается обычный массив.... после операции `json_decode($obj, true);`..... соответственно взять можно так `$arr['result'][0]['ID']`

Comment: Я под столом, спасибо тебе. Пойду спать, говорю же на поверхности все было